# How to handle post request when user hits submit on very basic node.js/html login page

Tags: html, node.js

I have created a login page using some HTML/CSS and I want the user to enter a pre-determined password, if the password is correct, they can enter the site, if not, they can't. I have looked up a lot of tutorials/sites etc. but they either use Mongodb to create unique passwords or else use Passport which is not what I'm looking for. I realise having a pre-determined password is not best practice but it suits for the scope of what I'm doing. I plan to change it once I get a basic set up going.

There is a fully functioning site when the user logs in, I just have very little experience with Node.js and not really sure how to handle the post request

This is my the form part of my HTML page (login.ejs)

```js
 <form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
  </div>
  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Login</button>
 </form>
```

And this is my part of my server.js file

```js
var express = require('express');
var config = require('./config');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mandrill = require('mandrill-api/mandrill');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//other stuff
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
 //user enters predetermined password
 //user hits the submit button
//if password = "login"
//go to home page
//if password != "login"
//go to error page

});
```

Answer (score 0):

modify client side code as

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Login</button>
</form>
```

and modify server side code as:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

if (req.body.name == "login")
  res.redirect('/home');
if (req.body.name != "login")
  res.redirect('/error');
});

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
  // If you are using ejs, you can render ejs
  res.sendFile(__dirname + 'path_to_folder_containing_htmls/home.html');
});

app.get('/error', function(req, res) {
  // If you are using ejs, you can render ejs
  res.sendFile(__dirname + 'path_to_folder_containing_htmls/error.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to specific the `action` attribute of the `form` to be the node route you want to send to. Your `form` will simply change to:

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Login</button>
</form>
```

In your `node` file, since you are using `body-parser` it is very simple to access the body of the `POST` request.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    var data = req.body.name;

});
```

Where `name` is the value of the `name` *attribute* on the `input` tag in your `form`.